# Recover deleted files from ext4 - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, testdisk, undelete

Well, I finally did it. I noticed a folder of my original drawings going back 4 months was missing from its usual spot. With reference photos and palettes and all, there are maybe 700 files in that folder and it's just gone. The backup on a memory stick isn't up to date, of course. I tried `testdisk` and found

```
X8526001 drwx------  1000   1000         0 11-Nov-2020 02:17 Comics
```

The only problem is there's no option to Undelete between List and Image Creation like it shows in the screenshots I'm following, instead it suggests Superblock and when I choose that, this is what I get. [image: several superblocks followed by To repair the filesystem using alternate superblock, run fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock -B blocksize device]

Can I do that safely? There are other files on the drive I don't want to lose.

At this point I don't even know if I can recover the files but if anyone can walk me through this variation, that would be awesome.

My parting advice is don't keep important folders on the desktop where they can get dragged into the recycle bin. I'm pretty sure that's what happened last night.